# How do i get a fixed time in a fixed timezone in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create a Time/DateTime object that always represents "8am in New York", regardless of DST. How can i achieve this ?

One suggestion in the Rails documentation was to use

```
Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

in the following manner

```
around_filter :set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
  if logged_in?
    Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone) { yield }
  else
    yield
  end
end
```

But i would like to avoid touching thread variables (which is what Time.use_zone is doing)

Comment: Is it possible to just render all times in user local time using [`in_time_zone`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].parse('8:00')
```

That will handle day light savings time issues

```
> eight_am = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].parse('8:00')
=> Fri, 22 May 2015 08:00:00 EDT -04:00

> eight_am.in_time_zone('America/Los_Angeles')
=> Fri, 22 May 2015 05:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could approach the problem this way:

```
ny = Time.new(Time.now.year,Time.now.month,Time.now.day,8,0,0,"-05:00")
```

This will return an object `ny` that is set for 8:00 AM EST (New York) for the current day on any day that you execute it.

Comment: Okay. This solves the problem. But if i want to display this time in another timezone, there are problems. For eg, `ny.in_time_zone('America/Los_Angeles')` gives Fri, 22 May 2015 06:00:00 PDT -07:00. I would expect it to be 5am.